# Mixing Anonymous Authentication with Windows Authentication in IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis-7

Is there any possible way to mix Anonymous Authentication with Windows Authentication, or even Basic Authentication in IIS 7?  My ideal setup would all attempt to authenticate with Windows or Basic Authentication and if that fails fall back to Anonymous Authentication.

The problem I'm running into is that with any of the possible combinations I choose in IIS 7, if Anonymous Authentication is enabled it always defaults to anonymouse regardless of what else is enabled.  I understand that this is by design, I'm just trying to find a way around it.

For the record, I'm not attempting to mix Forms Authentication with Windows Authentication, as that's not applicable in my situation.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve. You can mix "anonymous" authentication and Windows Authentication by simply using Windows Authentication. You would then restrict permissions such that some files and folders were not available to the Application Pool's user account and others were. Remember that even Anonymous Authentication is not really anonymous. Every site runs under the context of a set of credentials. In IIS6 for example, that account is typically NETWORK SERVICE. If you need the "anonymous" user to have limited access to some domain resources, then run the Application Pool under a low-level domain account.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Thomas. I guess I should have mentioned that this isn't really for "authentication" per se. I'm being tasked with having a page pull user info from the logged in user's Windows account if possible, if not then just allow the same page to be displayed with no information prepopulated.

Comment: That doesn't neccessarily work. Any view requested through a controller that has authorization enabled and includes content like CSS or JS files will use the domain user to try and access those files, causing you to have to give extra file system permissions to those users.